# how can i set div opacity only not text?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I want to use opacity only for div not on the text. i use some code for div opacity but it show me text opacity also. i do not want to show the text opacity. my code is here.

```
.opabenner {
width:569px;
height:100px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
background:#06F;
top:587px;
filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* IE */
   -moz-opacity:0.6; /* Mozilla */
   opacity: 0.6; /* CSS3 */
z-index:9999;
  }
 .tit {
position: absolute;
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
width: 580px;
  }


  <div class="opabenner"> 
         <h1 class="tit">Step inside love in 2014 and join today for FREE!</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 9):

use `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);` remove `opacity: 0.6;`

[**Sample Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCm87/16/)

Comment: yes thanks it's working. but is it works in all the browser?

Comment: @user3197474 : i think ie does not supports...

Comment: google is your friend: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: Also: http://caniuse.com/css3-colors

Answer (score 0):

Use RGBA colors for the container

```
p{
    color: red;
}

#transparent{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); /* 0.1 alpha = 10% opacity */
}
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/EfDZC/